# How do you sort multiple objects that contain arrays representing scores?

Tags: javascript

Given an array of objects like this:

```
competitors = [{
    name: "Alice",
    scores: [3,7,8,2,5]
}, {
    name: "Bob",
    scores: [4,4,5,6,8]
}, {
    name: "Carol",
    scores: [5,3,2,7,6]
}];
```

Given that lower scores are better, how can I sort them (rank them 1-3) such that the winner is the one who wins the most comparisons within each index?

For example, with Alice, Bob, and Carol, Alice should win because she has 3 wins (3<4<5, 2<6<7, 5<6<8) out of a possible 5.

A more complicated example is

```
competitors = [{
    name: "Dave",
    scores: [8,1,1,8,4]
}, {
    name: "Eve",
    scores: [1,5,4,5,2]
}, {
    name: "Frank",
    scores: [6,2,3,4,7]
}];
```

Here, Frank loses (1 win: 4<5<8), while Dave (2 wins: 1<2<5, 1<3<4) and Eve (2 wins: 1<6<8, 2<4<7) tie. So repeating the process with just Dave and Eve, you can break the tie. Eve wins the tie-breaker with 3 wins, 2 losses. The final ranking is Eve, Dave, Frank.

I will always know ahead of time the number of scores each competitor has (let's call it *numJudges*), as well as the range of possible scores (let's call it 1-*numCompetitors*). I'm also not concerned about browser support, other than webkit's javascript engine, so that means support for ECMAScript 5 and some 6 ([es5-compat-table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/)) like the array functions **every**, **map**, **filter**, and **reduce**.

Comment: I would do something with the sum of the items ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762589/fastest-javascript-summation ... is this some inspiration to you?

Comment: I'm already comparing sums of scores at a previous step of my ranking algorithm. If the sums tie, I go on to this kind of tie-breaker (the last of 4 steps).

Comment: What if two competitors have the same (lowest) score at some game?

Comment: For future reference: two by two comparisons don't work because it allows for cyclical ranking:  Alice: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] Bob: [2, 5, 4, 1, 3] Carol: [5, 1, 2, 3, 4] (example given by @DaveS)

Comment: It we're comparing two competitors, then it won't happen, because at this point in my algorithm, I'm dealing with an odd number of scores per competitor. If we're comparing three or more competitors, and two or more tie, then I would have to recurse over the set of competitors that tied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it often helps breaking a a big task like this down into stages. I doubt if it's efficient, but it might be useful to you.

To begin: get an array containing the results for each competitor:

```
function getScores() {
  return competitors.map(function (el) {
    return el.scores;
  });
}

var scores = getScores();
```

Then pull out the individual game information:

```
function getGames(scores) {
  var games = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = scores[0].length; i < l; i++) {
    games.push(scores.map(function (el) {
      return el[i];
    }));
  }
  return games;
}

var games = getGames(scores);
```

Find the winners of each game:

```
function findWinners(games) {
  return games.map(function (el) {
    return el.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, el));
  });
}

var winners = findWinners(games);
```

And finally, update each competitor with their results.

```
function applyWinners(winners) {
  winners.forEach(function (el, i) {
    var competitor = competitors[el];
    if (!competitor.results) competitor.results = [];
    competitor.results.push(i);
  });
}

applyWinners(winners);

console.log(competitors) // Alice wins [0, 3, 4], Carol wins [1, 2]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/JNAY2/)

Comment: This looks promising. I'll just have to recurse on winning and losing sets of competitors when I have more than three competitors, or in cases like my 2nd example with Dave, Eve, and Frank.

Comment: This worked with modifications to the applyWinners function for recursion.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I prefer @Tibos answer but this one is *simpler*.

You can use a sorting function ([`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)):

```
function getWins(competitors, competitor) {
  var scores = competitor.scores;
  var wins = 0;

  for (var i = 0, n = scores.length; i < n; i++) {
    var win = true;

    for (var j = 0, m = competitors.length; j < m; j++) {
      // Do not compare the competitor with himself
      if (competitors[j] !== competitor) {
        // Do not count a win if someone beat him
        if (competitors[j].scores[i] > scores[i]) {
          win = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (win) {
      wins++;
    }
  }

  return wins;
}

// Sort competitors according to their wins
competitors.sort(function(a, b) {
  return getWins(competitors, b) - getWins(competitors, a);
});
```

Comment: This would get *really* slow if the list of competitors is long, because you'd be doing (num scores * num competitors) operations on every comparison ... an O(n^3) algorithm.

Comment: @Pointy I'm not too concerned about speed, because I'm actually limiting the size of the scores arrays as well as the number of competitors. The ranking algorithm that this is a part of will typically have an odd number of scores (usually between 3-11) and no more than 20 competitors.

Comment: @Florent, this kind of sort (two-by-two comparisons) has the problem that among three or more competitors, there can be ties that if compared 2-by-2 and 2-by-2 and 2-by-2, as in a 3-way tie, you can end up with a cyclical ranking like competitor #1>#2>#3>#1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

A special compare function that computes the wins on the next level for a tie can do this:

```
function compareArray(a, b) {
    for (var i=0; i<a.length && i<b.length; i++)
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return a[i] - b[i];
    return a.length-b.length;
}
function addWins(c) {
    var w = new Array(c.length);
    for (var i=0; i<numJudges; i++) {
        // if two players have scored equally, the first will win
        var l = 0;
        for (var j=1; j<c.length; j++)
            if (c[j].scores[i] < c[l].scores[i])
                l = j;
        w[l] = (w[l]||0)+1;
    }
    for (var i=0; i<c.length; i++)
        c[i].wins.push(w[i]||0);
}

for (var i=0; i<competitors.length; i++)
    competitors[i].wins = [];
competitors.sort(function(a, b) {
    var samelevel = competitors;
    do {
        var o = - compareArray(a.wins, b.wins)
        if (o != 0)
            return o;
        var len = samelevel.length;
        samelevel = samelevel.filter(function(c) {
            return compareArray(c.wins, a.wins) == 0;
        })
        addWins(samelevel);
    } while (samelevel.length < len);
    return - compareArray(a.wins, b.wins);       
});
```