# how can take sum of array element using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a Array

```
 var Mark = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

& I want following results after applying javascript

```
var result=15;
```

Am using for loop

```
var result= 0;
for(var i = 0; i < Mark.length; i++)
{
    result += Mark[i];
}
```

this code correct or not,
I'm sure there is a better way then straight iteration,
 anyone please help me

Comment: Looping is the best way.

Comment: This code is absolutely correct. For more ways look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762589/fastest-javascript-summation

Comment: You could make `result= result+ Mark[i];` into `result += Mark[i];`but other than that I don't see any real way to improve upon this. What do you mean by a "better way"? What's wrong with this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most **fastest** way will probably be using a **simple loop** as you created.

Here's a different approach using [`Array.Reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var sum = Mark.reduce(function(prev, curr) { return prev + curr; }, 0);
```

Comment: this isn't a better way

Comment: Why not? It's in the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Example:_Sum_up_all_values_within_an_array

Comment: so what? you're argument is invalid Andreas.

Comment: @vsync - Define better..You can do a lot of things with a loop but I'm pretty sure you dont.

Comment: This answer may not be useful, it's still not harmful, I don't understand why this deserves a downvote.

Comment: @vsync, i agree it's not an argument, but "this isn't a better way" isn't a really good argument to

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature

Comment: but it is. he asked for a better way. it's obvious as gravity that using a callback function on each array item and having to know what `reduce` does isn't more readable or faster than a plain-old 30+ year old, 2 lines loop

Comment: @vsync- I agree with that. A straight forward loop will probably be the fastest way to sum up an array.

Comment: Take a look at the code here and you will understand:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @KD read the doc too, and learn, don't just look for the answer.

Comment: @AmirPopovich this is not the fastest way, but I support this as a best approach take a look at these times http://fiddle.jshell.net/8c58vmvn/ even underscore is faster than the array reduce

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Mark = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0, l = Mark.length;

while (l--) sum += Mark[l];

console.log('sum is: ', sum);
```

```html
open console...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fastest if you cache the array's length and then do a reverse loop on it:

```
var arr = [1,2,3],
    sum = 0,
    i   = arr.length;

while( i-- )
    sum += arr[i];  // 6
```

Comment: The OP asked for better, not faster

Comment: who are you, his lawyer? please explain why do you think this is not the absolute best way to do this, in your unprofessional opinion.

Comment: your way is faster and that is not up to discussion, but faster doesn't mean better, if you are so close minded to not see that who is the unprofessional?
I repeat what I have already said, my aim is to open the mind of the developer, not to make it a monkey solving problems.

Comment: lots of words, but this isn't a philosophy class, it's a dead simple question with a single answer. all the other answers aren't better in any way, they are ways to get to a goal, not **the** way. yeah I could have listed here many creative ideas how to achieve the goal, but what's the point, they are all **bad** practices and shouldn't ever be used for such simple things. under the hood they do the same, so why not go straight to the point with minimum code a monkey couldn't understand. always resort to the most basic code if possible.

Comment: Dude, really? Single answer? you are so closed. I'm sorry for you.

Comment: nice one, interesting.

Comment: @dariogriffo - anyway, he asked for better, not "other". and better != other.

Answer (score 0):

This a bit playing with words, but if your array is actually only made of consecutive integers starting from `0` to `m` or more generally from `n` to `m` with a constant common difference `d` (or step if you prefer), you can do something which is both better and faster ;)

In the case you described

```
var n = 1;
var m = 5; // (the length of your array)
var d = 1; // you increment with for each element
// n m and d describe [1,2,3,4,5]

var sum = ((m * (m + 1) / 2) - ((n - 1) * n / 2)) * d;
```

No looping needed, but this works only with matching problems for [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

Joke aside, looping is generally a good thing, as long as you don't nest too much of them depending  on the same variables boundaries.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you to take a look to underscore

http://underscorejs.org/

This library will make your live easier in javascript.

And this is how you make a sum with it

```
var Mark = [1,2,3,4,5];
var sum = _.reduce(Mark, function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with underscore.js. It's pure js

Comment: yeah so he should include a whole huge library just to sum up an array? you're kidding me.

Comment: underscore is pure js, I just made a suggestion form him to start taking a look at something that will help him in the javascript world.

Comment: @vsync is up to the OP, I just made a suggestion, as I see the OP is new on js, so it will be good to know some things beside manual looping. Better now, than in 1 year. We have to encourage good coding , or that is my aim here.

Comment: Then why underscore and not loadash? it's much faster. (if we're in business of talking about good practices)

Comment: @vsync because I wanted to

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
var result= 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < Mark.length; i++)
 {
    result+= Mark[i];
 }
```