# Multiplying array elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know the fastest and most efficient way to multiply array elements together using javascript.

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
```

So the outcome would total 10.

Comment: a quick search returned this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762589/fastest-javascript-summation

Comment: `4*3*2*1` is 24, not 10.

Comment: I've let the stack down.

Answer (score 5):

First, those values are strings, not numbers, so the first thing to do is make them numbers:

```
 array.map(Number)
```

Then multiply with `.reduce`

```
 array.map(Number).reduce(function(product, value) { return product * value; });
```

*edit* — a comment wisely notes that the `*` operator will try to convert its operands to numbers anyway. With the explicit conversion to numbers, you could add a filter to see if there were any `NaN` values produced, but `NaN` spreads like cancer so it really wouldn't matter. Consider the numeric conversion optional.

Now, in *general*, if I were getting an array of numbers-as-strings from an API, I'd be inclined to do an explicit conversion, because in a sense that means that there's really something wrong with the design of the API. I'd prefer to isolate any "interesting" code from weird stuff like that.

Comment: You don't need to do that, since Javascript does an implicit conversion.

Comment: @Buzinas hey you're right!  Still I'd be inclined to do it if I knew I had an array of strings that were *supposed* to be numbers, but might not be.

Comment: @Buzinas oh wait that's stupid :) The same thing (`NaN`) will happen with the implicit conversion!

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient/performant way will be always to use regular loop:

```
var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4'], i = array.length, result = 1;
while (i > 0)
  result *= array[--i];
```

But since that kind of performance will never matter in the real world, I suggest you to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

var result = array.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a * b;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Downvoted because the answer isn't right. The question was about speed and efficiency, using a for loop is substantially quicker.

Comment: @photoionized I see, that's true, thanks for informing :)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest form of loop is standard `for`, See **[map vs for-loop performance test](https://jsperf.com/map-vs-for-loop-performance/6)**.

**NOTE :** The slower is **map()** function like you can see in test.

```js
var Array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var total=1;

for (var i = 0; i < Array.length; ++i) {
    total *= Array[i];
}

alert(total);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Probably true! Though function calls are heavily optimized, a simple loop is almost certainly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Fast and efficient, go with a good old for loop, see http://jsperf.com/reduce-v-for-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce

```
var sum = array.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
```

with arrow functions in ES6, it is even simpler.

```
sum = array.reduce((pv, cv) => pv+cv, 0);
```

or with for loop

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; ++i){
 total += array[i];
}
```

and with crazy way

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
sum = eval(a.join("+"));
```