# grabbing values from label and adding them in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to grab all the values from the label with class price and add them using jQuery. Now actual webpage is different but to understand the concept I am only putting minimum code here. There are 3 labels for prices, and 1 more for total:

```
<label class="price">120</label>
<label class="price">250</label>
<label class="price">342</label>
<label id="total"></label>
```

I read that `.each()` can be used but I could not understand how to use it for this purpose.
I have uploaded jsfiddle over here http://jsfiddle.net/vivpad/cysjtrh8/1/

Comment: Updated your fiddle example. [http://jsfiddle.net/cysjtrh8/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/cysjtrh8/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var total = 0;
    $('label.price').each(function(){
        var value = parseFloat($(this).text());
        total += value;
    });
    $('#total').text(total);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/cysjtrh8/5/)

Comment: Simple and readable. Why someone would want to overcomplicating it... (referring to my own answer)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be simplest and easiest solution. I will rate it as correct one

Comment: @A.Wolff that's why genius you are .. you have more and more of solutions to do the job .. and that is what I know about A.Wolff :)

Comment: @VivekPadhye Thanks , and Good Luck to you

Answer (score 2):

You could get total price mapping `.price` elements text:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#total').text(function () {
        return $('.price').map(function () {
            return +$(this).text()
        }).get().reduce(function (pv, cv) {
            return pv + cv;
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: interesting use of reduce.

Comment: @Jai From [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762589/fastest-javascript-summation)  But that's not really optimized and not really readable. I find mohamed's answer better imho

Answer (score 1):

Note that you need to add jquery to your jsfiddle.

Also - you don't need to use .each - you can use arrays as well. Which simplifies it much and it is more efficient. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/vivpad/cysjtrh8/9

```
var sum = 0;
var prices = $("label.price");
for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
    sum += parseInt($(prices[i]).text());

$("#total").text(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var total = 0;
    $('.price').each(function() {
        var temp = $(this).html();
        total += parseFloat(temp);
    });
    $('#total').html(total);
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atadcsku/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var labelvalues = $('label').map(function () {
     return $(this).text();
 }).get();
 var total = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < labelvalues.length; i++) {
     total += labelvalues[i] << 0;
 }
 $("#total").text(total);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/next2u/cysjtrh8/11/)

Here I am using [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function to translate all items to new array of items. And add the elements in the array.