# How to write a function that gets the sum of an array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following:

```
var numSum = function(set) {
  for(i = 0, i < set.length, i++) {
      var arrayValue = set[i];
      var totalValue = arrayValue + 
  }
}
numSum([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

But all I get back is

> Uncaught Syntax Error

. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `total = set.reduce (function (a, b) { return +a + b;});`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762589/fastest-javascript-summation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For loop need `;` not `,`

It should be

```
for(i = 0; i < set.length; i++)
```

Shortcode of `x=x+y` is `x+=y` .

But you are doing it in wrong format.

It should be

```
totalValue += arrayValue
```

If you declare variable inside loop it'll create every time with the loop.

declare it outside of the loop.

Like this

```
var totalValue=0;
for(i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
      var arrayValue = set[i];
      totalValue+= arrayValue ;
}
```

you don't need to declare extra variable to hold.

Try like this

```
var numSum = function(set) {
  var totalValue=0;
  for(i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
       totalValue += set[i]; 
  }
  return totalValue;
}
numSum([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/p7v8sch8/)**</kbd>

You can do it using **[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**.

Try like this

```
var sum = [1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(prev, curr) { return prev + curr; });
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/o5ceocwq/)**</kbd>

Comment: `prev`, `curr` - `pv`, `cv` name mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

The following changes are required:

1. initialize `totalValue` outside the loop
2. use the increment-assignment operator correctly

It should be

```
var numSum = function(set) {
  var totalValue = 0;
  for(i = 0, i < set.length, i++) {
      totalValue += set[i];
  }
}
numSum([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Do it Like this.

```
var numSum = function(set) {
    var arrayValue = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
        arrayValue += set[i];

    }
    return (arrayValue);
};
console.log(numSum([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

So You need to change few Things in urs code

1. Structure of [**For Loop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
2. use of Assignment operator. it should be like `x+y` or `x+=y`

few improvment

1. You can use only one variable to store sum and can return that.

Answer (score 0):

There are typo mistakes

```
var numSum = function(set) {
  for(i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {  // replace ',' to ';'
      var arrayValue = set[i];
      var totalValue += arrayValue; //  += operator is short of totalValue = totalValue  + arrayValue
  }
}
numSum([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You got "Uncaught Syntax Error" for this line

```
var totalValue = arrayValue +
```

this should be

```
totalValue += arrayValue;
```

Your numSum  function will be like

```
function numSum (set) {
  var totalValue = 0;
  for(i = 0, i < set.length, i++) {
    totalValue += set[i];
  }
  return totalValue;
}
numSum([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this:
var numSum = function(set) {
                var arrayValue = 0;
                for(i = 0 ; i < set.length ; i++) {
                     arrayValue += set[i];                    
                }
                return arrayValue;
            }
            alert(numSum([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```